# Cast control does not appear on the status bar and app lock in V3

Tags: android

I am integratingV3 version in my app.. Notification  controls and app lock controls does not appear for the device which initiated the casting . if i connect from the other devices i could see the controls..

My cast provider is as follows

```
 public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
        public static final String CUSTOM_NAMESPACE = "urn:x-cast:com.test.cast.player";

    //    @Override
    //    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
    //        List<String> supportedNamespaces = new ArrayList<>();
    //        supportedNamespaces.add(CUSTOM_NAMESPACE);
    //        CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
    //                .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
    //                .setSupportedNamespaces(supportedNamespaces)
    //                .build();
    //        return castOptions;
    //    }


        @Override
        public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
            List<String> supportedNamespaces = new ArrayList<>();
            supportedNamespaces.add(CUSTOM_NAMESPACE);

            NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
                    .setActions(Arrays.asList(MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_SKIP_NEXT,
                            MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK,
                            MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_STOP_CASTING), new int[]{1, 2})
                    .setTargetActivityClassName(CustomExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
                    .build();

            CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
                    .setImagePicker(new ImagePickerImpl())
                    .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
                    .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(CustomExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
                    .build();

            return new CastOptions.Builder()
                    .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
                    //.setSupportedNamespaces(supportedNamespaces)
                    .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context appContext) {
            return null;
        }

        private static class ImagePickerImpl extends ImagePicker {

            @Override
            public WebImage onPickImage(MediaMetadata mediaMetadata, int type) {
                if ((mediaMetadata == null) || !mediaMetadata.hasImages()) {
                    return null;
                }
                List<WebImage> images = mediaMetadata.getImages();
                if (images.size() == 1) {
                    return images.get(0);
                } else {
                    if (type == ImagePicker.IMAGE_TYPE_MEDIA_ROUTE_CONTROLLER_DIALOG_BACKGROUND) {
                        return images.get(0);
                    } else {
                        return images.get(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late to help you, but I'll answer in case this helps others.  I wrestled with this issue for several days.  In the end the problem turned out to be in the custom receiver app we developed, not in the Android app.  The presence of the playback controls in the sender app (the Android side) depends on receiving exactly the right payload in the messages sent via the message bus in the media namespace (`urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media`).  So if your receiver app is not providing all of the correct data structures, or sending things in an unexpected sequence, the playback controls will not show up on the Android side.  To debug this you'll need to compare the logs from an app that works with the one that doesn't.  You can see what messages are coming back to the Android sender by adding a listener for the media namespace channel:

```
public static final String MEDIA_NAMESPACE = "urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media";

private Cast.MessageReceivedCallback messageReceivedCallback = new Cast.MessageReceivedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(CastDevice castDevice, String namespace, String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received message (" + namespace + "): " + message);
    }
};

castSession.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(MEDIA_NAMESPACE, messageReceivedCallback);
```

In my case there were two problems.  The receiver app was not sending the volume in the correct format, and we were not sending out an initial 'IDLE' message that included all of the correct media information.  Any deviation from the expected message format can result in a parse error on the sender side that breaks the normal flow.  If that happens you won't see any information for the loaded media or the playback controls when you begin casting.  The first message sent out always seems to be an 'IDLE' message, and it looks like this in our app:

```
{
   "type":"MEDIA_STATUS",
   "status":[
      {
         "mediaSessionId":1,
         "playbackRate":1,
         "playerState":"IDLE",
         "currentTime":0,
         "supportedMediaCommands":15,
         "volume":{
            "level":1,
            "muted":false
         },
         "media":{
            "contentId":"http://your.server/movie.mp4",
            "streamType":"BUFFERED",
            "contentType":"application/x-mpegurl",
            "metadata":{
               "metadataType":1,
               "images":[
                  {
                     "url":"http://your.server/some.jpg",
                     "width":200,
                     "height":200
                  }
               ],
               "title":"The Movie",
               "subtitle":"The Thing Worth Watching"
            },
            "duration":0,
            "customData":{
               "description":"A very cool movie that you will probably want to see."
            }
         },
         "currentItemId":1,
         "extendedStatus":{
            "playerState":"LOADING",
            "media":{
               "contentId":"http://your.server/movie.mp4",
               "streamType":"BUFFERED",
               "contentType":"application/x-mpegurl",
               "metadata":{
                  "metadataType":1,
                  "images":[
                     {
                        "url":"http://your.server/some.jpg",
                        "width":200,
                        "height":200
                     }
                  ],
                  "title":"The Movie",
                  "subtitle":"The Thing Worth Watching"
               },
               "duration":0,
               "customData":{
                  "description":"A very cool movie that you will probably want to see."
               }
            }
         },
         "repeatMode":"REPEAT_OFF"
      }
   ],
   "requestId":0
}
```

Your app might not be providing all of the same data, so your message will look a bit different, but you should make sure that all of the fields that you need are there and have the correct members and data types.

Comment: I have also discovered that monitoring the media namespace has side effects.  The dialog with the playback controls would very often show that no media was loaded and offer no controls, while there were working playback controls in the notifications and lock screen.  Not registering a callback for the media namespace seemed to fix this problem.  Not sure if it was monitoring the media namespace itself or the fact that I was monitoring more then one namespace, but this is definitely something else to watch out for if you're having issues with the playback controls.